# Is there a definitive list for the differences between the current version of SQL Azure and SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am a relative newbie when it comes to SQL Azure!! I was wondering if there was a definitive list somewhere regarding what is and is not supported by SQL Azure in regards to SQL Server 2008? I have had a look through google but I've noticed some of the blog posts are missing things which I have found through my own testing:

For example, quite a lot is summarised in this blog entry http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2009/12/main-differences-between-sql-azure-and.html

- Common Language Runtime (CLR)
- Database file placement
- Database mirroring
- Distributed queries
- Distributed transactions
- Filegroup management
- Global temporary tables
- Spatial data and indexes
- SQL Server configuration options
- SQL Server Service Broker
- System tables
- Trace Flags

which is a repeat of the MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394115.aspx

I've noticed from my own testing that the following seem to have issues when migrating from SQL Server 2008 to the Azure:

- XML Types (the msdn does mention large custom types - I guess it may include this?? even if the data schema is really small?)
- Multi-part views

I've been using [SQL Azure Migration Wizard v3.1.8](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) to migrate local databases into the cloud.

I was wondering if anyone could point to a list or give me any information till when these features are likely to be included in SQL Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get a hold of the February issue of SQL Server Magazine, there are two articles (I believe) that outline what Azure supports in relation to SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I'll try and see if I can get hold of a copy.. Anyone know of any handy web resource perchance??

Answer (score 1):

I was at an Azure training yesterday where it was confirmed that XML schemas are not supported. You may also find the e-clinic here https://www.microsoftelearning.com/eLearning/courseDetail.aspx?courseId=168190&tab=overview useful.

Answer (score 0):

This document is a little more detailed than the links you listed.  It's dated September 2009 but I believe is still mostly accurate.

http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9703594

One key paragraph from this document is:

Analysis Services, Replication, **Reporting Services**, and Service Broker are not currently provided as services on the SQL Azure.